# How can I set IDE level default package name in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

Is there a way to set the default package name in Intellij?

i.e. whenever I create a new Java class, the package would be defaulted to "org.my_domain_name.xxx"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the class by right-clicking on the package where you want the class to end up and choosing New --> Java Class, then IntelliJ will put the class in that package and will fill in the correct package statement for you.

Comment: Right, in other words the "Create New" -> *Class* function is context-sensitive to where you are hovering in the package tree. If you really want to override this you could write a `plugin` and create a new `Action`.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to move an existing class to the default package, you can right-click the class and select Refactor > Move... and enter an empty string in the "To Package:" field.